# To and FROM date calculation in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a table and its rows are reserved in To and From date format. It is reserved from some day to another.  Once reservation is made a ticket id is generated.

Now my requirement is, I need to categorize the tasks as active and historical. Historical must be, the TO date of ticketId must be older than yesterday. And active is the TO date must be greater than yesterday till any day.

How do I achieve this? I have difficulty figuring this out. To And From date is saved in below format in sql table:

```
From:2017-05-04     TO:2017-05-18
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: If the date columns are actually date type they don't have any format. They're dates. And surely you know how to compare dates with < and > ?

Comment: Provide sample records and code to illustrate your problem better

Comment: I know I can use  ReserveToDate <=  DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1); as historical task. But I cant do this in sql query. Can this be done in stored Proc? or code behind? ReserveToDate is a column in sql table. If the condition is true I need to display only those ticket id's

Comment: see answer please

Comment: @user3660473 what do you mean `categorize` anyway? Just add another field? Select the records in separate queries? Or somehow group the values and generate statistics?. Each case requires a different query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will work i think... try and revert

```
Select (case when cast(convert(varchar(10),[ReserveToDate],101) as date)>cast(convert(varchar(10),dateadd(d,-1,getdate()),101) as date) then 'Active' else 'Historical' end) as Status,* from Table
```

if you only want to show Historical ticketid then

```
    Select ticketid from Table where
cast(convert(varchar(10),[ReserveToDate],101) as date)<=cast(convert(varchar(10),dateadd(d,-1,getdate()),101) as date)
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to convert a date to string and back to date. This will only introduce conversion problems *AND* prevent the server from using any indexes. If someone wants to ignore the time element, a simple `cast(somefield as date)` will work without harming performance

Comment: Invalid column name 'To'. In this query where am I comparing ReserveToDate with datetime.

Comment: it is required to neglect the timestamp.

Comment: @Ravi no it is not.

Comment: Just replace to with the columnname you have

Comment: its working fine..But how can I make it more efficient

Comment: more efficient for what??

Comment: The multiple casts can't be made efficient because they prevent the use of indexes. Apart from that - efficient for what? Different requirements require different queries

Comment: in this query, status is a temp column, just used as an alias for the condition. How can I query the table with status column. I want to display ticketid where status ="Historical"

Comment: if you dont convert yesterday date then the date includes the time also. and if reservetodate alse have time then you will not get desired result